# Alignment of functions

Tags: c, compiler-construction, assembly, 68000

How do I make the functions align at 4-byte boundaries with GCC, target 680x0?

`-malign-functions=4` does not seem to do the trick, by itself anyway. Some kind of option meant to improve cache performance on 68020 and up perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-malign-functions=4` should do the trick but it can be overridden with the [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html) `aligned()`. Make sure that your code doesn't use this (for example with a macro).

Comment: Something for AROS contrib if it works I think. :-)  Anyway, no aligned attribute to be seen, besides I don't think that version of GCC supports that attribute. (Too old.) Do you think that it could be the linker which proceeds to misalign the code?

Comment: Been a while since I looked into the AROS source code :-( Is that PIC code? Otherwise, it's unlikely that the linker can interfere. Try "gcc -s" to get the assembly output and look for the `.align` meta-ops.

Comment: Don't know what it is actually, but good point about the PIC or not, makes sense. Thanks for the gcc -s tip, will try that when I get home. Thank you for creating AROS, that thing is finally shaping up the way I dreamt of in 1997, with Amiga hardware and software clones and AROS running on m68k. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

( Quoted from [linux.die](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) )

> -m4byte-functions
>
> **F-mno-4byte-functions**
>
> Force all functions to be aligned to a four byte boundary.

Comment: -mNO-4byte-functions - Interesting choice of name!

Comment: Haha, will try this later. :-)

Comment: Hm, while an interesting answer, it's not relevant to the 68000 line of processors. Quoting from Wikipedia "The M·CORE instruction set is very different from the 68K instruction set" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Freescale_products#M.C2.B7CORE-based